# Extract strings from a large JSON output in bash script into an array

Tags: arrays, json, bash, grep

The json file is next to my script in the same dir and contains a "title field with a value" near the beginning, see "Item1, Item2 and Item3" in the sample JSON. Near the end of each items section it has a section for "services" and there's a title for each service that it's tied to. The services can be as many as there are or none depending on the original item title.

All I want to do is search for a single service title...  i.e.  "STitle5"
And if it exists... just pop the main title of the item i.e. Item3 into an array. Based on the sample JSON below and the example just given, only Item1 and Item3 would get added to the array.

I've tried grepping with regex a bunch of different ways but can't seem to figure out how to go back and grab a specific string if something is found just after it. There can be thousands of entries in the JSON. I really don't need anything else from it so I thought just parsing the JSON as text direct would be the easiest way.

```
    [{"id_name": "Item1", "informational": {"values": ["werwe", "werwwe", "8", "ewrwrw", "werewrew", "64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125", "werw werwerw", "2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "fields": ["werwerw", "erwrwr", "wewrewrer", "werrwrwer", "werwerwrw", "werwerewr", "werwrwr", "stuff", "vendor_product", "version"]}, "role": ["Application Server"], "cpu_cores": ["8"], "create_time": "2017-04-03 16:32:27.738432", "mod_timestamp": "2019-06-26T01:17:23.933103+00:00", "title": "Item1", "family": ["dfsfd"], "OS": ["dfdsfsf"], "sdfdsfdsds": "fdsfdsf", "dsfdsfsd": ["64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125"], "host": ["dfdsfsdfsdfds"], "sdfdsfds": "sdfdsf", "vend": ["sdada"], "permissions": {"delete": true, "write": true, "user": "dsdsds", "group": {"delete": true, "write": true, "read": true}, "read": true}, "sdsdsdsdsds": ["dfsdfdsfdsfsd"], "_version": "3", "sgrp": "default", "object_type": "dfsfs", "mod_by": "user", "mod_time": "2019-06-25 13:09:47.543535", "_user": "user", "environment": ["dfsdfdfsd"], "description": "", "identifier": {"values": ["dfsdfdfdsffdfsdfs"], "fields": ["host"]}, "sdfdsfsfds": ["SMP"], "role": ["operating_system_host"], "mod_source": "REST", "_key": "afderea-be2d-47a6-9f0d-00857ereef6c", "version": ["2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "create_source": "unknown", "services": [{"title": "STitle", "_key": "865defee-d47f-4b8f-9435-bc4ere89e9b1f8d"}, {"title": "STitle2", "_key": "d9d5e231-3841-4376-a295-ea5fere95168482"}, {"title": "STitle3", "_key": "38165ff4-9da6-df-9a8b-a162aa7a68e8"}, {"title": "S
```

", "_key": "e2adb75e-9254-4774-b735-"}, {"title": "STitle6", "_key": "381f54d0-d759-43a3-94b3"}, {"title": "STitle7", "_key": "8253-f2b6a1d6f836"}, {"title": "STitle8", "_key": "bc69692b-48d8-4bd7-b62b"}]},

```
    {"id_name": "Item2", "informational": {"values": ["werwe", "werwwe", "8", "ewrwrw", "werewrew", "64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125", "werw werwerw", "2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "fields": ["werwerw", "erwrwr", "wewrewrer", "werrwrwer", "werwerwrw", "werwerewr", "werwrwr", "stuff", "vendor_product", "version"]}, "role": ["Application Server"], "cpu_cores": ["8"], "create_time": "2017-04-03 16:32:27.738432", "mod_timestamp": "2019-06-26T01:17:23.933103+00:00", "title": "Item2", "family": ["dfsfd"], "OS": ["dfdsfsf"], "sdfdsfdsds": "fdsfdsf", "dsfdsfsd": ["64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125"], "host": ["dfdsfsdfsdfds"], "sdfdsfds": "sdfdsf", "vend": ["sdada"], "permissions": {"delete": true, "write": true, "user": "dsdsds", "group": {"delete": true, "write": true, "read": true}, "read": true}, "sdsdsdsdsds": ["dfsdfdsfdsfsd"], "_version": "3", "sgrp": "default", "object_type": "dfsfs", "mod_by": "user", "mod_time": "2019-06-25 13:09:47.543535", "_user": "user", "environment": ["dfsdfdfsd"], "description": "", "identifier": {"values": ["dfsdfdfdsffdfsdfs"], "fields": ["host"]}, "sdfdsfsfds": ["SMP"], "role": ["operating_system_host"], "mod_source": "REST", "_key": "afderea-be2d-47a6-9f0d-00857ereef6c", "version": ["2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "create_source": "unknown", "services": [{"title": "STitle", "_key": "865defee-d47f-4b8f-9435-bc4ere89e9b1f8d"}, {"title": "STitle2", "_key": "d9d5e231-3841-4376-a295-ea5fere95168482"}]}, 

    {"id_name": "Item3", "informational": {"values": ["werwe", "werwwe", "8", "ewrwrw", "werewrew", "64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125", "werw werwerw", "2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "fields": ["werwerw", "erwrwr", "wewrewrer", "werrwrwer", "werwerwrw", "werwerewr", "werwrwr", "stuff", "vendor_product", "version"]}, "role": ["Application Server"], "cpu_cores": ["8"], "create_time": "2017-04-03 16:32:27.738432", "mod_timestamp": "2019-06-26T01:17:23.933103+00:00", "title": "Item3", "family": ["dfsfd"], "OS": ["dfdsfsf"], "sdfdsfdsds": "fdsfdsf", "dsfdsfsd": ["64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125"], "host": ["dfdsfsdfsdfds"], "sdfdsfds": "sdfdsf", "vend": ["sdada"], "permissions": {"delete": true, "write": true, "user": "dsdsds", "group": {"delete": true, "write": true, "read": true}, "read": true}, "sdsdsdsdsds": ["dfsdfdsfdsfsd"], "_version": "3", "sgrp": "default", "object_type": "dfsfs", "mod_by": "user", "mod_time": "2019-06-25 13:09:47.543535", "_user": "user", "environment": ["dfsdfdfsd"], "description": "", "identifier": {"values": ["dfsdfdfdsffdfsdfs"], "fields": ["host"]}, "sdfdsfsfds": ["SMP"], "role": ["operating_system_host"], "mod_source": "REST", "_key": "afderea-be2d-47a6-9f0d-00857ereef6c", "version": ["2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "create_source": "unknown", "services": [{"title": "STitle", "_key": "865defee-d47f-4b8f-9435-bc4ere89e9b1f8d"}, {"title": "STitle2", "_key": "d9d5e231-3841-4376-a295-ea5fere95168482"}, {"title": "STitle3", "_key": "38165ff4-9da6-df-9a8b-a162aa7a68e8"}, {"title": "SSTitle5", "_key": "e2adb75e-9254-4774-b735-"}, {"title": "STitle6", "_key": "381f54d0-d759-43a3-94b3"}, {"title": "STitle7", "_key": "8253-f2b6a1d6f836"}, {"title": "STitle8", "_key": "bc69692b-48d8-4bd7-b62b"}]}]
```

EDIT: can use id_name instead of title

EDIT: added better sample data

```
            {"id_name": "Item3", "informational": {"values": ["werwe", "werwwe", "8", "ewrwrw", "werewrew", "64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125", "werw werwerw", "2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "fields": ["werwerw", "erwrwr", "wewrewrer", "werrwrwer", "werwerwrw", "werwerewr", "werwrwr", "stuff", "vendor_product", "version"]}, "role": ["Application Server"], "cpu_cores": ["8"], "create_time": "2017-04-03 16:32:27.738432", "mod_timestamp": "2019-06-26T01:17:23.933103+00:00", "title": "Item3", "family": ["dfsfd"], "OS": ["dfdsfsf"], "sdfdsfdsds": "fdsfdsf", "dsfdsfsd": ["64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125"], "host": ["dfdsfsdfsdfds"], "sdfdsfds": "sdfdsf", "vend": ["sdada"], "permissions": {"delete": true, "write": true, "user": "dsdsds", "group": {"delete": true, "write": true, "read": true}, "read": true}, "sdsdsdsdsds": ["enttitle"=Item1, 'hostname=myHostname"], "_version": "3", "sgrp": "default", "object_type": "dfsfs", "mod_by": "user", "mod_time": "2019-06-25 13:09:47.543535", "_user": "user", "environment": ["dfsdfdfsd"], "description": "", "identifier": {"values": ["dfsdfdfdsffdfsdfs"], "fields": ["host"]}, "sdfdsfsfds": ["SMP"], "role": ["operating_system_host"], "mod_source": "REST", "_key": "afderea-be2d-47a6-9f0d-00857ereef6c", "version": ["2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "create_source": "unknown", "services": [{"title": "STitle", "_key": "865defee-d47f-4b8f-9435-bc4ere89e9b1f8d"}, {"title": "STitle2", "_key": "d9d5e231-3841-4376-a295-ea5fere95168482"}, {"title": "STitle3", "_key": "38165ff4-9da6-df-9a8b-a162aa7a68e8"}, {"title": "SSTitle5", "_key": "e2adb75e-9254-4774-b735-"}, {"title": "STitle6", "_key": "381f54d0-d759-43a3-94b3"}, {"title": "STitle7", "_key": "8253-f2b6a1d6f836"}, {"title": "STitle8", "_key": "bc69692b-48d8-4bd7-b62b"},{"id_name": "Item3", "informational": {"values": ["werwe", "werwwe", "8", "ewrwrw", "werewrew", "64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125", "werw werwerw", "2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "fields": ["werwerw", "erwrwr", "wewrewrer", "werrwrwer", "werwerwrw", "werwerewr", "werwrwr", "stuff", "vendor_product", "version"]}, "role": ["Application Server"], "cpu_cores": ["8"], "create_time": "2017-04-03 16:32:27.738432", "mod_timestamp": "2019-06-26T01:17:23.933103+00:00", "title": "Item3", "family": ["dfsfd"], "OS": ["dfdsfsf"], "sdfdsfdsds": "fdsfdsf", "dsfdsfsd": ["64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125"], "host": ["dfdsfsdfsdfds"], "sdfdsfds": "sdfdsf", "vend": ["sdada"], "permissions": {"delete": true, "write": true, "user": "dsdsds", "group": {"delete": true, "write": true, "read": true}, "read": true}, "sdsdsdsdsds": ["enttitle"=Item2, 'hostname=myHostname"], "_version": "3", "sgrp": "default", "object_type": "dfsfs", "mod_by": "user", "mod_time": "2019-06-25 13:09:47.543535", "_user": "user", "environment": ["dfsdfdfsd"], "description": "", "identifier": {"values": ["dfsdfdfdsffdfsdfs"], "fields": ["host"]}, "sdfdsfsfds": ["SMP"], "role": ["operating_system_host"], "mod_source": "REST", "_key": "afderea-be2d-47a6-9f0d-00857ereef6c", "version": ["2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "create_source": "unknown", "services": [{"title": "STitle", "_key": "865defee-d47f-4b8f-9435-bc4ere89e9b1f8d"}, {"title": "STitle2", "_key": "d9d5e231-3841-4376-a295-ea5fere95168482"}, {"title": "STitle3", "_key": "38165ff4-9da6-df-9a8b-a162aa7a68e8"}, {"title": "SSTitle4", "_key": "e2adb75e-9254-4774-b735-"}, {"title": "STitle6", "_key": "381f54d0-d759-43a3-94b3"}, {"title": "STitle7", "_key": "8253-f2b6a1d6f836"}, {"title": "STitle8", "_key": "bc69692b-48d8-4bd7-b62b"},{"id_name": "Item3", "informational": {"values": ["werwe", "werwwe", "8", "ewrwrw", "werewrew", "64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125", "werw werwerw", "2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "fields": ["werwerw", "erwrwr", "wewrewrer", "werrwrwer", "werwerwrw", "werwerewr", "werwrwr", "stuff", "vendor_product", "version"]}, "role": ["Application Server"], "cpu_cores": ["8"], "create_time": "2017-04-03 16:32:27.738432", "mod_timestamp": "2019-06-26T01:17:23.933103+00:00", "title": "Item3", "family": ["dfsfd"], "OS": ["dfdsfsf"], "sdfdsfdsds": "fdsfdsf", "dsfdsfsd": ["64432.5390625", "64432.55859375", "64432.36328125"], "host": ["dfdsfsdfsdfds"], "sdfdsfds": "sdfdsf", "vend": ["sdada"], "permissions": {"delete": true, "write": true, "user": "dsdsds", "group": {"delete": true, "write": true, "read": true}, "read": true}, "sdsdsdsdsds": ["enttitle"=Item3, 'hostname=myHostname"], "_version": "3", "sgrp": "default", "object_type": "dfsfs", "mod_by": "user", "mod_time": "2019-06-25 13:09:47.543535", "_user": "user", "environment": ["dfsdfdfsd"], "description": "", "identifier": {"values": ["dfsdfdfdsffdfsdfs"], "fields": ["host"]}, "sdfdsfsfds": ["SMP"], "role": ["operating_system_host"], "mod_source": "REST", "_key": "afderea-be2d-47a6-9f0d-00857ereef6c", "version": ["2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.16.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64", "2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64"], "create_source": "unknown", "services": [{"title": "STitle", "_key": "865defee-d47f-4b8f-9435-bc4ere89e9b1f8d"}, {"title": "STitle2", "_key": "d9d5e231-3841-4376-a295-ea5fere95168482"}, {"title": "STitle3", "_key": "38165ff4-9da6-df-9a8b-a162aa7a68e8"}, {"title": "SSTitle5", "_key": "e2adb75e-9254-4774-b735-"}, {"title": "STitle6", "_key": "381f54d0-d759-43a3-94b3"}, {"title": "STitle7", "_key": "8253-f2b6a1d6f836"}, {"title": "STitle8", "_key": "bc69692b-48d8-4bd7-b62b"}]}]
```

"**enttitle=**" field actually contains the exact value I need. The data file is all one line, no line breaks.

Comment: Maybe `jq` can be of help? See https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Btw., note that you have `Stitle4` instead of  `STitle4`, but I assume that's just a typo here.

Comment: i did see this before but I was trying to write this script without using tools that needed to be installed separately. -fixed typo. thx

Comment: Your sample data doesn't include any "STitle4". We have no idea which bit of information corresponds to "main title"  perhaps that's "title"? All that extraneous made up data doesn't contribute to understanding the issue at hand and in fact inhibits understanding because there's so much of it. Also, use `jq`.

Comment: Its STitle5... sorry. but I thought the first part was clear. CTRL F and type item1
you'll see the key is "title"  I need to get "Item1"  into an array if  STitle5 exists in Item1's services list. JQ requires additional installation. I wont be able to do that on some of the boxes i need to run this on unfortunately

Comment: JSON can't be parsed with regex. It's a shame you can't install a json-interpreter like [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html). With Xidel a simple query like `-e '[$json()[(services)()/title="SSTitle5"]/title]'` would be enough to put out: `["Item1", "Item3"]`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a roundabout way but i managed to get the results I wanted. I'm open to more efficient suggestions. But otherwise, heres what I wrote in case someone else ever needs to do something like this:

In a nutshell:

1. Grab all JSON data from the file and remove special chars -> store in var
2. Split new string data into an array using "id_name" as the delimiter
3. Loop through array and add each element to a new array only where STitle5 exists in the original element
4. Loop through the newest array and grep the pattern in between "id_name " and " informational"  which is the Item name add this to a new array

***NOTE:*** I ended up using "id_name:Item1" at the start instead of title:Item1... I'd prefer the title match but title appears in a million places. For now id_name at least is equal to title...though it doesnt need to be. I'll need to future proof this better.

```
        #!/bin/bash
        G_MATCH=$(grep -oP '(?=id_name).+?(?=id_name|}(](?!,)))' file.json | tr -d '[",:{}[]].')

        # split result to array using first name key as delim
        foo=$G_MATCH
        tmp="$foo"
        while [[ -n $tmp ]]; do
            tail=${tmp%id_name*}
            AR_ALL=("${tmp#$tail}" "${AR_ALL[@]}")
            tmp="$tail"
        done

        SUBSTRING="STitle5"

        # create new array only with items containing the specified service name
        AR_MATCHES=()
        for i in "${AR_ALL[@]}"
        do
                TEMP_VAL=$(echo $i|grep -o "$SUBSTRING")
                if [ -z "$TEMP_VAL" ]
                 then
                  echo "not adding..."
                else
                 AR_MATCHES+=("$i")
                fi
        done

        # create new array only with title names from first "name" key per line
        AR_TITLES=()
        for i in "${AR_MATCHES[@]}"
        do
                TEMP_VAL=$(echo $i|grep -oP '(?<=id_name )(.*)(?= informational)')
                if [ -z "$TEMP_VAL" ]
                 then
                  echo "not adding..."
                else
                 AR_TITLES+=("$TEMP_VAL")
                fi
        done

        printf '%s\n' "${AR_TITLES[@]}"
```

output:

```
        Item1
        Item3
```

Comment: A shell is an environment from which to call tools, it is not a tool to manipulate text. The guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call when text manipulation was required. Don't do this - it'll be incredibly slow and fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '/"STitle5"/{gsub(/^"|",$/,"",$2); print $2}' file
Item1
Item3

$ arr=( $(awk '/"STitle5"/{gsub(/^"|",$/,"",$2); print $2}' file) )
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
Item1
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
Item3
```

---

Update: given your new single-line input you could do this with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='{"id_name":' '/"SSTitle5"/{gsub(/^"|",$/,"",$1); print $1}' file
Item3
Item3
```

Note that in your new input all items are named "Item3" and "STitle" has been replaced with "SSTitle". Despite [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56812489/extract-strings-from-a-large-json-output-in-bash-script-into-an-array/56818207?noredirect=1#comment100193191_56818207), there is no field named `entitle` in your sample data.

Comment: if this would work it would be amazing. since what I'm doing now is incredibly slow. But I tried it and its not working right. I get empty array on the sample data. On the real data I get one result the rest of the array is empty. As if it only does the last one. The real data is massive but all one line. No breaks. I posted a better snippet and I also noticed theres a field i removed earlier called "enttitle" this is the exact value i need. im trying to understand what your command is doing to edit it right now and make it work for the new data sample. thx

Comment: The statement you now added that `The data file is all one line, no line breaks.` is enormously important to trying to parse the data file and of course a script designed to process records on individual lines as I posted based on the input you originally provided won't work when the data's all on one line. I might take a look later....

Comment: yeah I recognized that after you posted. I tried to separate the pieces for easier reading here originally.

Comment: thank you. I will try this on the larger data set. the enttitle is with two t's